# Entrar parametros y devolverlos como tipo JSON en C#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

¿ Como puedo pasar parametros con un tipo 'JSON' a un metodo en C# ?¿ Hay algun tipo JSON en C# usando alguna libreria standard de Microsoft Visual Studio ?

No me vale pasar parametros declarando una clase para luego serializarla y deserializarla.

Ejemplo sin JSON:

```
public bool MiFuncion(string parametro1, string parametro2, ref string respuesta1, ref string respuesta2) 
{ 
  // Codigo 
}
```

Ejemplo con JSON:

```
JSON parametros = {"parametro1":1,"parametro2":2};

public JSON MiFuncion(parametros) 
{ 
  // Codigo 
}
```

En este metodo me devolveria en el JSON la siguiente cadena:

```
{"respuesta1":"R1","respuesta2":"R2","retorno":true}
```

Comment: `System.Text.Json;` es la herramienta de .NET para manipular JSON. [Fijate Acá](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: Hay que preguntar exactamente porque quieres "trabajar" con JSON, ya que lo que generalmente se realiza es parsear a objetos. Para eso tienes por ejemplo estos tipos de datos [dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic), [JsonDocument (System.Text.Json)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=net-6.0) y [JObject (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm) y de la libreria de [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Comment: No me sirve el ejemplo de System.Text.Json ya que previo al envio de parametros me obliga a crear una clase con esos parametros. Lo que quiero es alguna libreria que trabaje directo con un tipo de dato que fuera JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias alternativas para trabajar con datos en formato Json en .NET, generalmente se parsea a un Objeto, ya que el objeto JSON que se recibe en .NET siempre sera "un string". Se puede utilizar estos tipos de datos que envio mas abajo de ejemplo. Deberias revisar estas opciones cual se ajusta a tu esencenario o requerimiento.

- [dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) ya interno de .NET, si bien no es para trabajar con datos JSON, tiene la misma caracteristica. Mira el ejemplo
- [JsonDocument (System.Text.Json)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=net-6.0) [System.Text.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/)
- [JObject (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm) y de la libreria de [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Incluso se puede parsear de un string "JSON" a un objeto dynamic. Pero en cada opcion tiene metodos o formas de recorrer o manuipular estos objetos. DEberias ver cual se ajusta a tu necesidad.

Por ejemplo, arme un demo para que puedas ver estas 3 opciones

- [DataJson - Dymamic-JsonDocument-JObject](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ea8zyv) https://dotnetfiddle.net/ea8zyv Puedes ejecutarla online

**OPCION 1: [dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)**

Aquí el codigo por ejemplo opcion con Dynamic. Si bien no es para trabajar con datos en json que recibes, puede mapearse facilmente
(deberias ver como se obtiene el objeto json, ya que dynamic es propio de .NET)

```
public static void Opcion1ConDynamic() 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Opcion 1: Dymamic");
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");

    var dataJson =  new {parametro1=1, parametro2=2};
    
    var respuesta = MiFuncionDynamic(dataJson);
    
    Console.WriteLine($"dataJson={dataJson}");
    Console.WriteLine($"respuesta={respuesta}");
}


public static dynamic MiFuncionDynamic(dynamic dataJson) 
{ 
    //{"respuesta1":"R1","respuesta2":"R2","retorno":true} 
    return  new {
                  respuesta1="R1", 
                  parametro2="R2",
                  retorno = true
             };
}
```

**OPCION 2: [JsonDocument (System.Text.Json)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=net-6.0) [System.Text.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/)**

Aqui ya es trabajar con datos en JSON (mira como parsea el string que recibes de tu fuente)

```
public static void Opcion2ConJsonDocument() 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Opcion 2: JsonDocument");
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");

    var dataJsonString =  @"{""parametro1"":1, ""parametro2"":2}";
    
    using JsonDocument jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(dataJsonString);
    JsonElement rootElement = jsonDoc.RootElement;
    
    Console.WriteLine($"jsonDoc={jsonDoc}");
    Console.WriteLine($"rootElement={rootElement}");

}
```

**OPCION 3: [JObject (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm) y de la libreria de [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)**

```
public static void Opcion3ConJObject() 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Opcion 3: JObject");
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------");

    var dataJsonString =  @"{""parametro1"":1, ""parametro2"":2}";
    
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(dataJsonString);
    
    Console.WriteLine($"jObj={jObj}");

}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Comment: Parece que la opción mas sencilla es usar dynamic o Newtonsoft.Json